# Can't connect to Ethernet but Wi-Fi can

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

I'm using UBUNTU14.04LTS, and it seems that I can't connect to Ethernet, but Wi-FI can.I believe the driver for finding Ethernet connection is working because the following output is produced...

`lemma@lemma:~$ modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-121-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     80B89D6BA6F4A4F4A917E3C
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E0A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-121-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline`

`lemma@lemma:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED

       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df100000-df13ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:12
       logical name: wlan1
       serial: 14:cc:20:13:00:88
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.4.0-121-generic firmware=0.29 ip=10.20.81.39 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn`

Comment: There is no driver loaded to handle the ethernet interface. You need one.

Comment: I have the driver installed that's why it's connected to Wifi right?